# Historical documents of Mount Athos

Tags: byzantine-empire, historical-research, greece

I have heard of a project of cataloging and digitizing of all of Mount Athos documents. Is there a website to find more information about this project, and to follow its progress?

I'm having a hard time finding anything on the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are referring to the collection of manuscripts from Mount Athos and from the monastery of Saint John the Theologian in Patmos which is being digitised by the [Institute for Byzantine Research](http://pandektis.ekt.gr/pandektis/handle/10442/9045?locale=en).

According to a [press release](http://www.epset.gr/en/Press-Center/News/manuscripts-abbey-patmos) in July 2012:

> The database contains information concerning archival material from the Athonite Archives and from the monastery of Patmos recorded on microfilms. Today, the collection includes 5009 Byzantine and Post-Byzantine manuscripts; 4902 manuscripts are kept in 11 monasteries of Mount Athos (e.g Haghiou Pavlou, Dionysiou, Docheiariou, Karakallou, Kastamonitou, Xeroptamou, Pantokratoros, Stavronikita, Hilandar, Protaton and Panteleimonos). The remaining 107 are preserved in the monastery of Saint John the Theologian in Patmos.

The archive appears to be searchable, or you can browse by title or subject.